# Export kernel module headers to userspace

Tags: linux, module, header, export, kernel

I am writing a Linux kernel module which need to export some header files to userspace.

I am wondering if there is any standard method which use Kernel package to do required sanitation of headers (For example something like "$(MAKE) -C $(KERNELDIR) M=$(PWD) headers_install" if exist).

Should i take care of headers manually?
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such functionality out of the box because most kernel modules which need something like that come with an extra "devel" package which contains the (cleaned) header files and probably a shared library to talk to the module.

As for cleaning your headers, I suggest to split the header files into a generic part (which you export) and an internal part (which only the kernel module can see). `typedef` is your friend.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it by adding 'header-y=' to one of the Kbuild under /include/uapi

Comment: This correctly answers the question "How to export kernel headers to userspace?", which is what I was looking for when I found the OP, +1.