# Make kernel headers available to user space

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I have written a custom device driver as an out of tree kernel module.
This device driver defines a set of ioctls that are needed by user space applications. The ioctls are defined in a custom header file.

What is the standard location where this header file should be installed? Should this be `/usr/include`? Or perhaps the same location where the standard kernel include files are installed?

I have read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6124238/export-kernel-module-headers-to-userspace) but it does not specify where the custom header files should be installed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you should treat your public user-space API headers like any others, and put them under `/usr/include`.  Either as a single file if it's a small API, or in a subdirectory.  Just make sure to provide only the necessary pieces in that header, and not the implementation details.  If you're going to produce a Linux package for developers, you'd usually name it like foo-dev (APT/Ubuntu) or foo-devel (YUM/RHEL).